# How to make RewriteCond+RewriteRule change domain2/folder1 to domain1/folder1

Tags: mod-rewrite, rewrite, rewritecond

There's actually 2 questions.

One is, how do I make RewriteCond+RewriteRule change domain2/folder1 to domain1/folder1

Actually what I want is any domain that tries to access folder1 that is not domain1 gets switched to domain1.  So for example  domain2.com/domain1/foo  -> domain1.com/domain1/foo as well as domain3.com/domain1/foo -> domain1.com/domain1/foo

This is what I tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}     !^domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/folder1/
RewriteRule ^/folder1/(.*)$  http://domain1.com/folder1/$1 [L,R=permanent]
```

But that doesn't work.  Next I tried some a simpler rule to see if I could narrow down the issue.

```
RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST}  domain2\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$        http://google.com/ [L]
```

I though that would make ANY request to domain2.com go to google.com so I tried `http://domain2.com/foo` but I get domain2.com/foo not google.com  If I go to `http://domain2.com` I get google. Why don't I get there if I go to `http://domain2.com/foo`?

What am I not understanding about mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. The above rules work. The issue was I actually had a "folder1" and inside was another .htaccess file.  DOH!